# Using a Temporary Table in a View in Order to Combine Two Queries

Tags: sql-server, view

I am trying to create a view using to two queries below and I get the error message **Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables.** Is there a way to do that or is there a way to combine the two queries below so I don't have to use a temp table?

```
 create view 
    [vw_Org_Hierarchy]
    as
    **--Query 1**
    SELECT     
    File_NBR, 
    Job_title, 
    First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Name, 
    CASE WHEN job_title IN ('Vice President', 'Sr VP & Chief Financial Officer', 
  'Sr. Vice President', 'Executive Manager') THEN 'Vice President' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Associate Vice President', 'Associate Vice President & CPO', 
'Associate Vice President & CIO') THEN 'Associate VP' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Acting Medical Director', 'Director', 'Deputy Controller', 'Director of Operations & Staff Dev') AND NOT (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) IN ('Michelle James', 'Edward Lachterman', 'Nafissa Hannat') 
THEN 'Director' 
WHEN (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) IN ('Michelle James', 'Edward Lachterman', 'Nafissa Hannat') THEN 'Director B' 
WHEN Job_title = 'Assistant Director' THEN 'Assistant Director' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Coordinator', 'Supervisor', 'Campus Administration Manager', 'Compensation & Benefits Manager', 'Cottage Manager', 'Manager', 'Office Manager', 'Operations Manager', 
'Recruiting Manager', 'Special Projects/Rep & Compliance Manager', 'Talent Manager', 'Youth Development Coordinator') OR ((First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) = 'Rosa Nunez Pena') THEN 'Supervisor' ELSE 'Worker' END AS Job_Category, Position_NBR,  Supervisor_Position_NBR, Mngr_FName + ' ' + Mngr_LName AS Manager
INTO **#STAFF**
FROM New_EEs.dbo.vw_ADPFile

**--Query 2**
WITH org AS 
 (SELECT 
 s.POSITION_NBR, 
 s.File_NBR,
 s.Name, 
 s.Job_Category
 FROM  **#STAFF**  AS s
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 
 s.POSITION_NBR, 
 s.File_NBR,
 o.Name, 
 o.Job_Category
 FROM **#STAFF**  AS s
 JOIN org o ON (o.POSITION_NBR=s.Supervisor_Position_NBR))
    SELECT 
    [Vice President] as 'Vice President', 
    [Associate VP] AS 'Associate VP',
    [Director] AS 'Director',
    [Director B] AS 'Director B',
    [Assistant Director] AS 'Assistant Director',
    [Supervisor] AS 'Supervisor', 
    [Worker] AS 'Worker', 
    POSITION_NBR,
    File_NBR
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM org WHERE 
            (POSITION_NBR IN 
            (SELECT POSITION_NBR 
            FROM **#STAFF**
            where Job_Category ='Worker'))
    ) AS p
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Name) FOR 
        Job_Category IN ([Vice President],[Associate VP],
        [Director],[Director B],[Assistant Director], [Supervisor], [Worker] )
    ) AS pvt
```

Comment: How about taking the SQL statement you use to fill #staff, make a sub query out of it and add it as a join to the two tables you're querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to combine the two is to move the first query into the CTE of the second. That looks like this:

```
WITH staff AS(
SELECT     
    File_NBR, 
    Job_title, 
    First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Name, 
    CASE WHEN job_title IN ('Vice President', 'Sr VP & Chief Financial Officer', 
  'Sr. Vice President', 'Executive Manager') THEN 'Vice President' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Associate Vice President', 'Associate Vice President & CPO', 
'Associate Vice President & CIO') THEN 'Associate VP' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Acting Medical Director', 'Director', 'Deputy Controller', 'Director of Operations & Staff Dev') AND NOT (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) IN ('Michelle James', 'Edward Lachterman', 'Nafissa Hannat') 
THEN 'Director' 
WHEN (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) IN ('Michelle James', 'Edward Lachterman', 'Nafissa Hannat') THEN 'Director B' 
WHEN Job_title = 'Assistant Director' THEN 'Assistant Director' 
WHEN job_title IN ('Coordinator', 'Supervisor', 'Campus Administration Manager', 'Compensation & Benefits Manager', 'Cottage Manager', 'Manager', 'Office Manager', 'Operations Manager', 
'Recruiting Manager', 'Special Projects/Rep & Compliance Manager', 'Talent Manager', 'Youth Development Coordinator') OR ((First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) = 'Rosa Nunez Pena') THEN 'Supervisor' ELSE 'Worker' END AS Job_Category, Position_NBR,  Supervisor_Position_NBR, Mngr_FName + ' ' + Mngr_LName AS Manager
FROM New_EEs.dbo.vw_ADPFile
),
org AS 
 (SELECT 
 s.POSITION_NBR, 
 s.File_NBR,
 s.Name, 
 s.Job_Category
 FROM  **#STAFF**  AS s
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 
 s.POSITION_NBR, 
 s.File_NBR,
 o.Name, 
 o.Job_Category
 FROM Staff  AS s
 JOIN org o ON (o.POSITION_NBR=s.Supervisor_Position_NBR))
    SELECT 
    [Vice President] as 'Vice President', 
    [Associate VP] AS 'Associate VP',
    [Director] AS 'Director',
    [Director B] AS 'Director B',
    [Assistant Director] AS 'Assistant Director',
    [Supervisor] AS 'Supervisor', 
    [Worker] AS 'Worker', 
    POSITION_NBR,
    File_NBR
    FROM
    (SELECT * FROM org WHERE 
            (POSITION_NBR IN 
            (SELECT POSITION_NBR 
            FROM **#STAFF**
            where Job_Category ='Worker'))
    ) AS p
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Name) FOR 
        Job_Category IN ([Vice President],[Associate VP],
        [Director],[Director B],[Assistant Director], [Supervisor], [Worker] )
    ) AS pvt
```

However, the #temptable was likely introduced into the query to increase performance. In SQL Server there is currently no way to force the creation of a materialized set within a view. So you can't write an equivalent query. You could try to force a blocking operator like a sort into the "staff" query (for example by adding a `TOP(<large number>)` and an `ORDER BY`. This could cause SQL Server to use a spool operator which is equivalent to using a temp table. However, most likely be counter productive because the additional cost of the sort will outweigh the gain achieved by the spool.

That means, if you are going this way you have to use other performance tuning methods. Make sure you have appropriate indexes and your statistics are up to date.